# ERROR: MAC did not verify! PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to update content in a JSF 2.0 webapp without refreshing the entire page.

This is my xhtml

```
<h:form id="form">  
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />  

    <p:poll interval="3"   
            listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />  
</h:form>
```

And my bean

```
package org.primefaces.examples.view;  

import java.io.Serializable;  

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;  

public class CounterBean implements Serializable{  

    private int count;  

    public int getCount() {  
        return count;  
    }  

    public void setCount(int count) {  
        this.count = count;  
    }  

    public void increment() {  
        count++;  
    }  
}
```

This compiles fine but when it runs I get the following error:

ERROR: MAC did not verify!

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706327/jsf-mojarra-2-1-to-2-2-migration-causing-viewexpiredexception