# JSF: Mojarra 2.1 to 2.2 migration causing ViewExpiredException

Tags: mojarra, jsf-2.2

I'm porting my applications from PrimeFaces 3.5.18 + Mojarra 2.1.26 to PrimeFaces 4.0.2 + Mojarra 2.2.4.

When I restart the server I get a ViewExpiredException.

Server log contains this: `ERROR: MAC did not verify!`

I know that by default MyFaces generates a random secret to encode the view state, so each time the server restart, a new random secret is generated. Is Mojarra 2.2 behaving the same way?

In that case, what context parameters do I need to set? Googling for Mojarra 2.2 context parameters the best I could find was [this](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/constant-values.html), but there are no SECRET or MAC_SECRETS parameters like in MyFaces

Thanks in advance,
Phillip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting ViewExpiredException in clustered environment while state saving method is set to client and user session is valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102645/getting-viewexpiredexception-in-clustered-environment-while-state-saving-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was this: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2553

Solved it by changing the state saving method to server.

Comment: javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD