# Spring Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload ? cluster mode

Tags: spring, jsf, wildfly

Hi I am very new to PrimeFaces, we have a web application which runs on cluster mode, the sessions are managed in redis server but I am getting ViewExpiredException when we use ROUND ROBIN algorithm for requesting server.

Java 8,
WildFLY 13.0.0 FINAL

I did looked into [Getting ViewExpiredException in clustered environment while state saving method is set to client and user session is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102645/getting-viewexpiredexception-in-clustered-environment-while-state-saving-method), as per this i changes in web.xml

Here how it looks like,

[image: Web.xml]

I am getting following errors

```
    23:53:29,401 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /xyz/views/user/list.xhtml: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression from [Module "org.glassfish.javax.el" version 3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1 from local module loader @2ea6137 (finder: local module finder @41ee392b (roots: E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules,E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:335)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:102)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:432)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:402)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:326)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:343)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:214)
    at com.xyz.core.util.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:40)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression from [Module "org.glassfish.javax.el" version 3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1 from local module loader @2ea6137 (finder: local module finder @41ee392b (roots: E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules,E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:79)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression from [Module "org.glassfish.javax.el" version 3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1 from local module loader @2ea6137 (finder: local module finder @41ee392b (roots: E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules,E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:59)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression from [Module "org.glassfish.javax.el" version 3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1 from local module loader @2ea6137 (finder: local module finder @41ee392b (roots: E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules,E:\wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:677)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at com.sun.el.lang.VariableMapperImpl.readExternal(VariableMapperImpl.java:76)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.readExternal(MethodExpressionImpl.java:324)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.readExternal(TagMethodExpression.java:158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1933)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1933)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1933)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1933)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:41)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: There is nothing in the stacktrace related to PrimeFaces. There is a CNFE... Off topic: And why are you running spring 'culstering' when you have a java ee server that already has clustering?

Comment: @Kukeltje my session is not expiring when we request to multiple servers, it's replicated but issue is i get ViewExpiredException in primefaces, for that issue i did configure the VIEW_STATE and key so that each server uses same key.